# How do I test an $httpBackend POST error state with AngularJS / Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to write a unit test for my Angular Service and here's a function in the service:

```
login = function(authObject) {
  deferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
    url: '/api/v1/session/create',
    method: 'POST',
    data: authObject
  }).success(function(response) {
    var user;
    if (response.status === 'ok' && response.user && response.authenticated === true) {
      user = response.user;
    }
    return deferred.resolve(response);
  }).error(function(data) {
    deferred.reject(data);
    return $state.go('api_error');
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

I can successfully test the `success` case with something like:

```
it('should go to the api error state', function() {
  var authObject;
  authObject = {
    username: 'a@b.com',
    password: 'c'
  };
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/v1/session/create').respond(someData);

  userService.login(authObject).then(function(response) {
    return console.log("not error", response);
  }, function(response) {
    return console.log("error", response);
  });
  return expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('api_error');
});
```

That works fine, however if I do:
`$httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/v1/session/create').respond(500, 'error');`, then the error case doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your `.then()` error callback to be called, the previous promise in the chain should result in error (e.g. throw an Exception) or be rejected.

Returning `500` will cause the `error` callback in your `login()` method to be called, but since that callback neither throws an Error nor gets rejected, your chained error callback won't be called.

E.g. changing:

```
}).error(function(data) {
    deferred.reject(data);
    return $state.go('api_error');
});
```

to:

```
}).error(function(data) {
    return deferred.reject(data);
    //return $state.go('api_error');
});
```

would work (but it doesn't do what you want :D).

---

I am not familiar with `ui-router`, but in this case it could be possible that `$state.go()` aborts the current execution chain, so I am not sure the following would work:

```
}).error(function(data) {
    $state.go('api_error');
    return deferred.reject(data);
});
```